# Child ul behind parent ul in css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists, z-index

I'm trying to make my dropdown menu with pure css3 but my child `ul` keeps showing on top of the parent. I've tried with `z-index -100`, removing the positive `z-index` value from the parent `ul`, but nothing happens.

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/z9kCx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9kCx/13/) here. Would that work?

I added menu and sub-menu classes to your `ul`s and edited your css a bit:

```
ul.menu li {
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
   float: left;
   background: #2A2A2A;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 15px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
   transition: all 0.5s;
   list-style-type: none;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    width: 145px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

ul.menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```